# What is `readUInt32BE` of nodeJS in Python?

Tags: python, node.js

I am translating a source of NodeJS to Python. However there is a function `readUInt32BE` that I do not quite understand how it works

Original Code

```
const buf = Buffer.from("vgEAAwAAAA1kZXYubG9yaW90LmlvzXTUl6ESlOrvJST-gsL_xQ==", 'base64');
const appId = parseInt(buf.slice(0, 4).toString('hex'), 16);
const serverIdLength = buf.slice(4, 8).readUInt32BE(0);
```

Here is what I have tried so far in Python

```
encodeToken = base64.b64decode("vgEAAwAAAA1kZXYubG9yaW90LmlvzXTUl6ESlOrvJST-gsL_xQ==")
appId = encodeToken[:4]
appId = appId.hex()
serverIdLength = ......
```

If possible, can you write a function that works the same as `readUInt32BE(0)` and explain it for me ? Thanks

Comment: BE is a common abbreviation of Big [Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming from the name that the function interpreters an arbitrary sequence of 4 bytes as an unsigned 32-bit (big endian) integer.

The corresponding Python function would be `struct.unpack` with an appropriate format string.

```
import struct


appId = encodeToken[:4]
serverIdLength = struct.unpack(">I", appId)[0]
# ">" means "big-endian"
# "I" means 4-byte unsigned integer
```

No need to to get the a hex representation of the bytes first. `unpack` always returns a tuple, even if only one value is created by the format string, so you need to take the first element of that tuple as the final value.